# If "a" prop is true, require also "b" and "c"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a type:

```
type Foo = {
  a: boolean;
  b: string;
  c: string;
}
```

How to adjust it so if `a` is `true`, `b and c` fields MUST be provided. But if `a` is `false or undefined`, `b` and `c` MUST NOT be provided?

Comment: [Discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions)

Comment: In which context do you need to validate this; in a constructor or in some form validation or somewhere else? It is unclear what you mean by "provided".

Comment: @Culme It's in REACT

Comment: Ive wanted to do similar in React with props like isLoading, error, and some king of data props, and found this useful - https://blog.andrewbran.ch/expressive-react-component-apis-with-discriminated-unions/ as it tries to take care of scenarios like not passing both `isLoading` and `error` both as truthy values at the same time, it can only be one or the other and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions), but beware that:

1. In general, *preventing* an object from having properties through TypeScript's type system is problematic because objects can have *excess properties*. TypeScript prevents assigning an object literal defining excess properties because it's a common programming mistake, but doesn't disallow it in the general case.
2. If `a` is optional and means that `b` or `c` shouldn't be there, `{}` (a completely empty object) is a valid `Foo`.

```typescript
type Foo =
    | {
          a: true;
          b: string;
          c: string;
      }
    | {
          a?: false;
      };

// Valid
const a: Foo = { a: true, b: "bee", c: "see" };

// Valid
const b: Foo = { a: false };

// Valid
const c: Foo = {};

// Invalid, but only if you're directly assigning an object literal
const d: Foo = { a: false, b: "whatever" };

// This is allowed, because an object can have excess properties
const someObject = { a: false, b: "whatever" } as const;
const e: Foo = someObject; // <== No error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeAUFdUA+UDeaMHoCGAXFMAE4CuEA3PoRgEZkDOlAlgHYDm9jBAMZtOvfoQC+DLLmmMiAfjIAzIgBtWdOVAn0UAen1QAauo4ATFILhd2UUrATJc9spRoAaKCygAiJhAQvl7CfppBOnqGJmaW1rbA3mTwiEguDqoa0LooBkamahZWNnahKc44OXlQAJJcAG6xXkxUiTZqIFAcylAgcFQA5BTQ5hzDgsAd9qysHDxc3Dz2XFBwTABWEBNQhcAQFOrFCVDmyU5pOK5QmZrNZL4A7gAWRHv1+76RudEAKk8crC6gPUajgDwg5maWyIVE0y1WGy2iUERBWL3eUAgAA9BBAZlAwBQ4JAKMAOHijnZWHAALYQADyiO2FyuNwgdz8z1eEHeFE+EmmUHi7HowsSEDOqSg1LpjM2E1oUGiAB4kGkAHKIfZEigoIA)

Comment: How about if the condition changed to be: only when `a` and `b` are both `true`, then `c` is required, otherwise `c` won't exists. Does discriminated union support this? Or if it is too expensive, maybe just define `c` optional is better `c?: string`.

Comment: @WayneMao - Do you mean something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxq37W)?

Comment: @t-j-crowder thanks for your example. not exactly, the case should be like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUCGAuKYAJwFcIBuTbAIwOLMuygGMB+AgZ2IEsA7Ac0oBfSugD0YqADUcAG24ATdMzi8uuAvEQpUGwqQgAaKLX1koI9OMkBJXgDc5i4wANmLljl4ByYCehgRBAcELx+ABQA7gAWoVAQAB7MwRxQgXCQRKAsscwA1qk4YGCyIACUyqrq+LAIyGh69EYmdAbGzAQARCEQnRaiElAAgrKy0k5KKmp+NVr1ujVNxqYAZnIh7V09fZZT6qZzOnprshstZs0dUN0Qvf2V0yyadUc1J2er65dbtzsDkiMxnZHPIFMYALbcDgcPj8KBuFwParPbQNRZtc7vaC7Kp+A4vNEELHLVrmHGPK6HQlQYmYr73axQYETCFQmECExIvwKFHzY70yxAA), note: the type def is just so far what I can do...

Comment: @WayneMao - I can't tell what you're trying to do. In particular, I don't get the comment on line 10 of that. In your first comment above, you said `c` is required when `a` and `b` are `true`. So line 11 would be valid, but the comment on line 10 says it isn't...?

Comment: @t-j-crowder sorry, my first post doesn't really represent the real case I met, the demo did. I didn't realize it become an issue and makes you confused. I thought they are just on the opposite and shouldn't affect that if Typescript can handle it or not...

Comment: @WayneMao - Are the comments in [your playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOrArW) accurate? (Also, please don't reuse identifiers, it hides errors by obscuring them with the error about the redeclared identifier.) I'd like to help, but I can't figure out what you're asking. That playground doesn't have any unions, discriminated or otherwise, so...?

Comment: @t-j-crowder Please check updated [demo](https://shorturl.at/bgxyF)

Comment: @WayneMao - It comes down to how type-safe you want/need to be. As you say, your version of `Foo` with the unions is a bit complicated (not really in your playground, but I'm guessing the real thing is more so), but it does provide type-safety. Your alternative with just `boolean` and an optional string for `c` is simpler, but less type-safe (you could easily end up with `{a: true, b: true, c: "x"}`, or `{a: false, b: true}`, both of which you've said are invalid). In terms of alternatives, you could use a generic conditional type with parameters for the types of `a` and `b`. That's...

Comment: ...a pain to use directly, you end up with things like `const a: Foo<true, true> = { a: true, b: true };`, which is repetitive ([example](https://tsplay.dev/wQq31w)). But you can fix that by inferring the generic type arguments. For that, you need a function (it can be a do-nothing function), so usage is like `const a = checkFoo({a: true, b: true});` ([example](https://tsplay.dev/N5QzBN)). If it happens you're *already* usually passing these into a function, great, you're sorted. If not, it's adding a **bit** more code (the unnecessary function call) but provides more...

Comment: ...type-safety. So again, it depends how important type-safety is in this case. Hope this helps!

Comment: @t-j-crowder The real business scene is we need to define the type the API returned. It is the backend side that provide this "if a:true/b:true then without c:string“ strategy. We hope to type it to safely use the data. It is very useful for the 2 demo you provided, I've learned a lot. But considering these 3 ways (including my last demo), I guess mine is althought a bit complicated, but easier for others to use/reference. Anyway, I have to say this is the most serious answer I've ever received on stackoverflow, thank you so much.

Comment: My pleasure @Wayne, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) in typescript.

The type might look something like this:

```
type Foo = 
  | { a: true, b: string, c: string }
  | { a?: false | undefined | null }
```

This accounts for the following cases:

```
const foo: Foo = { a: false } // valid
const foo: Foo = { } // valid
const foo: Foo = { a: true, b: "foo", c: "foo" } // valid

const foo: Foo = { a: true } // invalid
const foo: Foo = { a: undefined, b: "foo" } // invalid
const foo: Foo = { a: false, b: "foo" } // invalid
const foo: Foo = { a: false, b: "foo", c: "foo" } // invalid
```